# How to remove syntax error? Pinescript V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Any ideas on how to solve this syntax error?

```
//@version=5
    indicator(shorttitle="BB", title="Bollinger Bands", overlay=true, timeframe="",    timeframe_gaps=true)
    length = input.int(20, minval=1)
    src = input(close, title="Source")
    mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")
    basis = ta.sma(src, length)
    dev = mult * ta.stdev(src, length)
    upper = basis + dev 
    lower = basis - dev
    c= if src>upper
      c=src-upper  
    else   
      c=0
    or
      if src<lower 
      c=src-lower   
        else 
        c=0
plot(c,style=plot.style_columns)
```

Trying to create this indicator and need help with the programming

Comment: You can start by fixing your indentation.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple errors in this code from indentation to syntax. There's also an easier way to get the bollinger bands.  This is how I would do it based on what I get from your code.

```
indicator(shorttitle="BB", title="Bollinger Bands")

len = input.int(20, minval=1)
src = input(close, title="Source")
mult = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="StdDev")

[bbbasis, bbupper, bblower] = ta.bb(src, len, mult)

c = 0.0
if src > bbupper 
    c := src - bbupper
else if src < bblower
    c := src - bblower

plot(c,style=plot.style_columns)
```